# Ruby, bubble_sort_by(arr), code is working but returning original array

Tags: arrays, ruby, loops, yield, bubble-sort

Short question:
Why my method (which is accepting blocks) is returning original array instead of modified.

Long question:
Code like this:

```
def bubble_sort_by(array)
  array.each_with_index do |outer, outer_index|
    array.each_with_index do |inner, inner_index|
      if yield(outer, inner) > 0
        if outer_index < inner_index
              p "outer after if: " + outer        # for debugging, indented for clarity
              p "inner after if: " + inner        # for debugging
          outer, inner = inner, outer
              p "outer after swap: " + outer      # for debugging
              p "inner after swap: " + inner      # for debugging
        end
      end
    end
  end
end

bubble_sort_by(["hi","hello","hey"]) do |left,right|
  left.length - right.length
end
```

In irb I see that the values of `outer` and `inner` are swapped(sorted), but the return value is still the original array.

```
2.3.3 :1223 >     end
"outer after if: hello"
"inner after if: hey"
"outer after swap: hey"
"inner after swap: hello"
 => ["hi", "hello", "hey"] 
2.3.3 :1224 >
```

I wrote earlier similar method `bubble_sort` (without block) with very similar code and the original array was replaced by swapped values there.
I don't understand why the swapped values aren't saved in method mentioned here, and instead I receive original array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change value of array item. This is working code:

```
def bubble_sort_by(array)
  array.each_with_index do |outer, outer_index|
    array.each_with_index do |inner, inner_index|
      if yield(outer, inner) > 0
        if outer_index < inner_index
              p "outer after if: " + outer        # for debugging, indented for clarity
              p "inner after if: " + inner        # for debugging
          outer, inner = inner, outer
              p "outer after swap: " + outer      # for debugging
              p "inner after swap: " + inner      # for debugging

          # change value array item
          array[inner_index] = inner
          array[outer_index] = outer
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: This answer also solved my next problem, with not sorting array where the largest element is at first place(or shortest at last place). 
Only replacing this: 
`outer, inner = inner, outer` 
with this: 
`array[outer_index], array[inner_index] = array[inner_index], array[outer_index]` 
is not sorting the array in "worst case scenario". 
I need to analyze deeper what is happening now and then. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You're swapping the local variables only

```
outer, inner = inner, outer
```

This will not modify `array`, to change the array you must use `[]=`

```
array[n] = value
```